# Lettered scrollbar shifts down when UIRefreshControl is active?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a UIRefreshControl that accesses online data and refreshes the table view. On that same table view, I am also using the:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

To create a lettered scrollbar so that the user can easily sort through the data. For some reason, when I try to refresh the tableview by dragging down, the scroll bar jumps down when the refreshing wheel comes into view and jumps back up once refreshing is complete.

Has anyone ever suffered this issue before and, if so, is there an easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I had to was convert the UITableView to a UITableViewController and then the UIRefreshControl to the control of the controller. Then I showed the controller like this:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController *) content {
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [[self view] frame];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```